# C# login using SQL Server database not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, authentication

I need to open a new form if the user name and the password is correct but I can't get this code to work, if I enter a correct username or a password it does nothing.

```
private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      string connection = @"Data Source=DX-PC;Initial Catalog=login;Integrated Security=True";
      SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection);

      cn.Open();

      string userText = user.Text;
      string passText = pass.Text;

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(Username, '') AS Username, ISNULL(Password,'') AS Password FROM log WHERE Username = @username and Password = @password", cn);
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username", userText));
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("password", passText));

      SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      try
      {
          dr.Read();
          if (dr["Username"].ToString().Trim() == userText && dr["Password"].ToString().Trim() == passText)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("This message won't Display");
          }
      }
      catch
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password");
      }

      dr.Close();
      cn.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Could be a dozen reasons. You `Initial Catalog=login` does not exist. You make typos. You have added weird values to your database, why else would you use trim on a string that came from database? It is more likely to use trim on the text that came from the textbox.

Comment: Don't join this club: http://plaintextoffenders.com/

Comment: Surely you have some kind of a sign something is not working. An error? Exception? Please do share...

Comment: No errors,and the connection works perfectly if i type a wrong username or a password the invalid messagebox comes up, the only issue is that if i type the correct details the " MessageBox.Show("This message won't Display");"  will not be displayed. 
sorry if i am not clear, i am still new to c#

Comment: Also: be aware that the called to `dr.Read()` **could fail** if no data is found. It returns `true` when it's successful - so you should change that line to `if (dr.Read()) { .... }` to avoid any surprises....

Comment: This can easily be debugged. Check `dr["Username"]` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is in the:

```
                if (dr["Username"].ToString().Trim() == userText && dr["Password"].ToString().Trim() == passText)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("This message won't Display");



                }
```

section of your code.  Try adding an else as follows:

```
                if (dr["Username"].ToString().Trim() == userText && dr["Password"].ToString().Trim() == passText)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("This message won't Display");



                } else {
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}!={1}, {2}!={3}"
                        ,dr["Username"].ToString().Trim(),userText,
                         dr["Password"].ToString().Trim(),passText
                    );
                }
```

and you will probably find your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
        cn.open
        MySqlDataAdapter LoginAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        dynamic CommandQuerry = @"SELECT * From users WHERE Username='" + UsernameField.Text + "'AND Password='" + PasswordField.Text + "';";
        MySqlCommand LoginCommand = new MySqlCommand(); //The Login Command
        MySqlDataReader LoginDataReader = default(MySqlDataReader); //Create a reader variable to check login details.

        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
              LoginCommand.Connection = SelectedSchoolDB;
              LoginCommand.CommandText = CommandQuerry;
              LoginAdapter.SelectCommand = LoginCommand;

              LoginDataReader = LoginCommand.ExecuteReader();

              if (Convert.ToInt32(LoginDataReader.HasRows) == 0)
              {
                     DialogResult a = MessageBox.Show(@"Invalid username/password, please try again", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
              }
              else
              {
                     LoginDataReader.Close(); // Close The reader
                     This.FormName.Hide(); //Close the login form
                     Newform.ShowDialog(); //Show the new form
              }
cn.close()
}
```

Hope This code helps :)

Comment: If You need the explanation of each code let me know.

Comment: warning: sql injection hazard above

Comment: @spender Can you explain this more please? how is it possible? and how to prevent it? plus I think sql injections works for websites not C# application

Comment: SQL injection is a problem wherever you have unfiltered user input going in as inline SQL.  As in http://xkcd.com/327/ you can have someone enter SQL in through the UsernameField or the PasswordField which will be run.  Try adding typing the following in the UserNameField text box: '; CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InjectionRules]([UserID] [int] NOT NULL); --

Answer (score 0):

Though the Code you provided is vulnerable to SQL Injection & XSS, but to answer your question, string comaprision on filter criterion at SQL queries are case insensitive where as on .NET code above would be case sensitive.